# How to build a telnet application using spawn? How to give user input to "send" command?

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to build a telnet application in TCL.

1. I have to do prompt the user whenever the device is prompting.
2. have to expect any prompt to make it generic.

   I tried:

   ```
   expect -re {^(.*)$}
   ```

   to match anything.
3. I have to get input from user and the send it to the spawned process.
4. Print whatever the device gives for the command given by the user .and again from step 1.

My problem is that I cannot use `gets stdin` while doing expect.

Example:

```
while {1} {    
    expect {
        -re {^(.*)$}  {
            gets stdin cmd
            send "$cmd"
         }
    }
    # print the device output for $cmd here 
}
```

So , Is there any way to give **user input to "send" command** ?

Comment: Why don't let the user use the application directly? Or just `interact`?

Comment: I need to store the results for every specific commands. If you use INTERACT, you cannot take details of every command you give.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I am trying to build the same function what interact is doing but I can manipulate commands and results of it.

Comment: Why can't you use `gets stdin`? What happens? There are also `send_user` and `expect_user` commands in expect.

Comment: Are you using `exp_internal 1`? An excellent tool for developing an expect script.

Comment: expecting `^(.*)$` will **always** match. Surely you must be able to either expect something more concrete or limit the user's prompt.

Comment: @glennjackman `gets stdin` isn't working in spawn.        `expect_user {string}` expects us to type the string .`send_user` operates like puts.But my app is to send user input

Comment: `gets stdin` is not working . It does not wait for us to give input.

Comment: Please describe the details of “not working”. Is it blocking? Is it ignoring what you type? Are you sure it is asking at the point where you think it is? (That RE will match in places where you might not expect…) [Pun intended.]